# Clicking a submit link in rvest

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape data from a website using `rvest`. I read in the html of the page and then extract the form. Thereafter I make changes in the form using `rvest::html_form_set` and then submit it. After looking at the form, I realized there is no submit button. The button available on the website is an anchor tag with a href to a script. I tried using `rvest::session_follow_link()` but am unable to get the data. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
trademark_search_page <- rvest::session('https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx')
      search_form <-  rvest::html_form(trademark_search_page)[[1]]

      search_form <- search_form %>% rvest::html_form_set(`ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBWordmark` = 'Bull',
                                                          `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TBClass` = 32)

      resp <- trademark_search_page %>% rvest::session_submit(search_form) %>% 
        rvest::session_follow_link(xpath = '//a[@id = "ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch"]')
```

Any suggestions on what I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be tricky to do with `rvest` because the button references a javascript script. If you're open to other tools, here's how to do it with `RSelenium`

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)

# define url ---------------------------------------------------------
url <- "https://ipindiaonline.gov.in/tmrpublicsearch/frmmain.aspx"


# define search terms ------------------------------
word_mark <- "Bull"
class_search_term <- "32"

# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4548L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# fill in the form ------------------------------------------------
# this finds the html element for each part of the form
# and fills it in with the value we want

# Wordmark
remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ContentPlaceHolder1_TBWordmark")$sendKeysToElement(list(word_mark))

# Class
remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ContentPlaceHolder1_TBClass")$sendKeysToElement(list(class_search_term))


# click submit button ---------------------------------------

remDr$findElements("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_BtnSearch")[[1]]$clickElement()
```

Here's what the page that leads to looks like:
[image: search results]

After you get to this page you can get list of the more details links using `rvest`

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

# pull html from page
html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

# find all the html elements with the .LnkshowDetails class

more_details_butons <- html %>% read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(".LnkshowDetails") %>%
  html_attr("id")
```

then you could loop though all the buttons and click on them or pull data

Comment: And I suppose with RSelenium you could click on the 'Show Details' link too, right?

Comment: yep! Here's how to click on the first one: `remDr$findElements("id", "ContentPlaceHolder1_MGVSearchResult_LnkShowDetails_0")[[1]]$clickElement()`

Comment: Alright thanks, will give this a try

Comment: No problem. I edited the answer to include a bit more about how to find the more details buttons